# cURL can't connect through working proxies?

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I have a script that tests a compiled list of HTTP proxies to see if they can connect to a specified website. If they connect, and the correct page results are returned, they are added to a list of working proxies; however, even if I test about 30,000 proxies at a time....none of them come back working.

Yet, when I check a random selection of them in a proxy checker, quite a large portion of them come back working.

http://puu.sh/3EJDo.png (picture of connection results)

Even when I specify the proxy type to HTTP, cURL never manages to make a connection to the webpage and return the webpage contents.

Note: I am setting a user-agent.

**As you can see, no results are returned. The contents of the webpage, if any are retrieved, should be posted in the textbox.**

http://puu.sh/3EK4z.png

Don't think this will really help, but here's my cURL request setup:

```
foreach($proxies as $proxy){
        $proxy_split = explode(':',$proxy);

        if(!in_array($proxy_split[1], $this->banned_ports)){
            $checked[] = $proxy;

            $this->curl->addSession('http://www.removed.com', array(
                CURLOPT_PROXY => $proxy,
                CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE => CURLPROXY_HTTP,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
                CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1',  
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
             ));
        }
    }
```

Added the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION option to double check, and it still does not manage to return any page contents/make a connection.

Comment: You ever find a solution to this?